# Consume Kafka Avro messages in go

Tags: go, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to consume Kafka messages in avro format but I'm not able to decode the messages from avro to json in Go.

I'm using the Confluent platform (3.0.1). For example I produce avro messages like:

```
kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}'
{"f1":"message1"}
{"f1":"message2"}
```

Now I consume messages with the go Kafka libary: sarama. Plain text message are working fine. Avro message have to be decoded. I found different libs: github.com/linkedin/goavro, github.com/elodina/go-avro

But after decoding I get a json without values (both libs):

```
{"f1":""}
```

goavro:

```
avroSchema := `
{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}]}
`
codec, err := goavro.NewCodec(avroSchema)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
bb := bytes.NewBuffer(msg.Value)
decoded, err := codec.Decode(bb)
log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s", decoded))
```

go-avro:

```
schema := avro.MustParseSchema(avroSchema)
reader := avro.NewGenericDatumReader()
reader.SetSchema(schema)
decoder := avro.NewBinaryDecoder(msg.Value)
decodedRecord := avro.NewGenericRecord(schema)
log.Println(decodedRecord.String())
```

msg = sarama.ConsumerMessage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just found out (by comparing binary avro messages) that I had to remove the first 5 elements of the message byte array - now everything works :)

```
message = msg.Value[5:]
```

Maybe someone can explain why

Comment: The answer of "Maybe someone can explain why": when you produce a message with schema registry serializer, Kafka client's message serializer add schema id in the first bytes of the message, if you use the cline deserializer, it checks that first byte to detect schema id and fetch it from schema registry(if needed), but when you don't use standard Kafka client's deserializer, so you need to skip those first bytes.

Answer (score 18):

[The first byte is a magic byte (0). The following 4 bytes are the avro schema ID](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format)

Which is only really useful if you use the Confluent schema registry.